# Macbook Pro DVD Burner Testing

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, macbook-pro

How does one test the Macbook Pro DVD Burner?  It keeps giving medium errors AND hardware errors and I cannot even burn a single DVD, and I've used 3 different disk manufacturuers with the same disk type (DL DVD+R).

I've run the Apple Hardware Tests, but I do not believe that this tests the "burning" aspects of the drive.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What are the brands you've tried?

What are the error codes you're getting?

Have you tried running Apple Software Updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product ended up actually being a "known issue" and the guys in the Apple Store replaced it with no questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have tested it and found it to fail, at least for double-layer media. (This is a recent enough machine that it is spec'd to write DVD's, right?)  I'd try single-layer too, for whatever more I might learn, but it sounds like repair time.

Comment: Yes - this was just purchased a little over a month ago.  i5 Macbook Pro (17")